# SQL merge 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql query involving 2 tables and try to add a third one.

These are the tables

1. FreeBookPos

- FreeBooK_ID
- ArticleNr
- Amount

2. FreeBook

- ID
- BookNr
- Date

3. FreeFields

- FreeFieldType
- Value
- SQLPrimeKey

The first two are linked this way

```
select FreeBookPos.ArticleNr, Format(FreeBooking.Date, 'yyyy_MM') as dt,
SUM(CASE WHEN FreeBook.BookNr = 0 THEN FreeBookPos.Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalEntryAmount,
SUM(CASE WHEN FreeBook.BookNr = 1 THEN FreeBookPos.Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalLeftAmount
From FreeBookPos
INNER JOIN FreeBook on FreeBookPos.FreeBook_ID = FreeBook.ID
group by FORMAT ( FreeBook.Date, 'yyyy_MM'), FreeBookPos.ArticleNr
order by dt, ArticleNr
```

Now I need to add the table 3. This table is linked via SQLPrimeKey to FeeBook table ID. I then need to have only the fields where FreeFields.Value 2 or 4 and FreeFields.FreeFieldType = 54.

I tried various options with join but never get the result. Would I need to first join table 2 and 3 and then with 1 in a separate step?

Table 1: FreeBookPos

```
FreeBook_ID  ArticleNr Amount
1             145       12
2             145       6
3             143        4
4              145       1
5              145       42
```

Table 2: FreeBook

```
ID  BookNr  Date
1     1       2012-05-19
2      -1     2012-05-21
3      1      2012-05-22
4     -1      2012-05-24
5     -1      2012-06-25
```

Table 3: FreeFields

```
SQLPrimareyKey FreeFieldType Value
1                54             1
2                 52           2
3                 54           4
4                  54          2
5                  54          2
```

Result should be:

```
ArticleNr Dt      TotalEntryAmount TotalLeftAmount
143      2012-05      4                0 
145      2012-05     0                 -1
145      2012-06      0                 -42
```

Comment: provide your expected output in tabular format

Comment: Show us sample results, and the combined result - all as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Hint: `from a join b on a.id=b.id join c on c.id=b.id`. You can use multiple conditions on the `on` if you need to. In your case, since you're not using columns from third table in your select, you could just use `where exists`

Comment: What kind of calculation to you apply so you get negative numbers in the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below -

```
select FreeBookPos.ArticleNr, Format(FreeBooking.Date, 'yyyy_MM') as dt,
SUM(CASE WHEN FreeBook.BookNr = 0 THEN FreeBookPos.Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalEntryAmount,
SUM(CASE WHEN FreeBook.BookNr = 1 THEN FreeBookPos.Amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalLeftAmount
From FreeBookPos
INNER JOIN FreeBook on FreeBookPos.FreeBook_ID = FreeBook.ID
inner join FreeFields on FreeBook.ID=SQLPrimareyKey
where value in (2,4) and FreeFieldType = 54
group by FORMAT ( FreeBook.Date, 'yyyy_MM'), FreeBookPos.ArticleNr
order by dt, ArticleNr
```